# How do I access these xml files from some other machine?

Tags: olap, olap-cube, cubes, olap4j

I need to access the cubes through olap4j API in java application. XML cubes files will be available in some other IP server. For Example, XML files will be in 192.168.1.1 IP and C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geomondrian\WEB-INF\queries path. How do I access these xml files from some other machine.

```
Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");

                // Create connection.
                connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.33:5433/simple_geofoodmart?user=postgres&password=postgres;**Catalog=E:/xml/simple_foodMart.xml**;JdbcDrivers=org.postgresql.Driver;");
                OlapConnection olapConnection =
                    ((OlapWrapper) connection).unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
```

I am not able to access the catalog which is available in other IP. find the below my catalog URL path. How can i access?

**Catalog=//192.168.1.10/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/geomondrian/WEB-INF/queries/simple_foodMart.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Mondrian uses Apache VFS to fetch the catalog from the provided URL. You have a lot of options. The catalog could be on the local file system, or it could even be on an HTTP server, in which case you pass the web URL of your catalog directly.

It also supports much more complex scenarios. Apache VFS allows you to define any type of file handler you need. You could, for example, create a handler which responds to requests in the "bacon://" protocol and generate the catalog dynamically.